# Broken characters and gnome applications

Tags: fonts, desktop-environments, gnome-classic

I'm kinda new to Linux community, made some research and found nothing similar to this.
Everything works fine, but I'm facing this very weird symbols on VirtualBox and Flameshot on Gnome(screenshot tool).

I had an Ubuntu installation before (same 18.04) and everything was fine. I reinstall from scratch for a random reason and now I see this.

The only thing I made different this time is trying to install unity. I had to roll back because it did not work well with three monitors.

I've attached a screenshot by the end of the post.

[Broken characters on virtualbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG6Y2.png)

Running locale, this is what I get:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like nice Greek characters, but probably you are expecting normal Roman characters here. Virtualbox is a QT application, so QT may be malconfigured. You should then see the same also in VLC.

Comment: If the issue had been caused by a Qt confusion related to the locale, you would have expected Portuguese strings in this case and not Greek...

Comment: I have changed everything back to en-us and still no results. I'm still doing some research and what could be done o QT side to fix this, yet not too sure what.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by the worst path: Reinstalling Ubuntu.
Tried to do so many things with QT but nothing seems to work.
Still waiting to see if someone in the future had another way to address this.